# Does AndroidStudio memory profiler show a PssTotal data?

Tags: android, android-studio, memory-profiling

AndroidStudio memory profiler shows a chart with different memory usages, eg. Java, Native, Graphics and so on. As far as I known the only way to get those data is reading */proc/{pid}/smaps*, or get from *dumpsys meminfo*, which is the same. It seems AndroidStudio only shows "Pss Total", but the actual physical memory usage should be "Pss Total" and "SwapPss Dirty".
How could I get "SwapPss Dirty" in memory profiler view?

[image: View from AndroidStudio Memory Profiler]
[image: Result of dumpsys meminfo]